# Contour plot from data

Tags: matlab, contour

I have values of `x`, `y`, `z` where `x`, `y` coordinates and `z` the value of a property at `x`, `y`. How I can plot a contour in Matlab ? Following the instructions of contour help is gives me straight lines which is wrong why `x`, `y` are scattered values.

Is there any alternative?

This is a sample of my data

```
x           y           z

374268.5544 675550.1559 1
374386.6404 675496.6808 1
374423.119  675481.0927 1
374140.9671 675521.0678 1
374197.4762 675542.8119 1
374123.3594 675476.2379 1
374364.7803 675599.1029 2
374290.032  675614.6592 2
374126.762  675618.8996 2
374315.5478 675612.5549 2
374273.1932 675615.7666 2
374212.045  675644.172  2
374170.9248 675649.8851 2
374322.0588 675730.4371 3
374275.3753 675719.5573 3
374203.5859 675682.2803 3
374258.9523 675725.4594 3
374082.6761 675480.1364 3
374196.921  675689.9341 3
374252.6329 675716.9851 3
374214.0248 675697.2011 3
```

What I did was:

```
[x y]=meshgrid(x,y); 
z=meshgrid(z);
contour(x,y,z);
```

That gave me straight vertical lines. Then I tried the following:

```
contour(x,y,z,[1,1]);hold on
contour(x,y,z,[2,2]);hold on
contour(x,y,z,[3,3])
```

which created just one contour line.

Comment: This question is very unclear - you have given us nothing to help you with! You need to post 1) the code you're using, 2) some sample data, and 3) an image of the incorrect plot, otherwise no one will be able to help you

Comment: You should edit all of this information into your post - the edit link is just below the tags, above the comments, and to the left of your name

Comment: I'm glad you got an answer! Thanks for editing the post. In the future, you don't need to sign your name to your posts, because your name appears on the bottom right anyways. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create the grid myself.

```
[xi, yi] = meshgrid( min(x):1: max(x),  min(y):1: max(y));
zi = griddata(x,y,z, xi,yi);
contour(xi,yi,zi,[2,2])
```

The following commands will give you an idea of what is happening:

```
figure()
surf(xi,yi,zi);
shading interp; hold on;
plot3(x,y,z,'kx')
```